# Preg_match() Filter HTTP Request Containing Symbols %, $

Tags: php

I am learning things about using preg_match() regex to filter Http Request. I have this Request again

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.copyscape.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.copyscape.com/login.php
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 74
Cookie: ck=BXLD2UDMUA88KWGC0GK8WCGOC; PHPSESSID=8cup5f02hbetnbfbbv9vug37q0
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R
```

Now i want to Extract **only** this Part using **php preg_match()**

```
login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R
```

I didnt get a Reply yesterday for this, Question is how do i go about this? No offence i am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to get that using preg_match while you can directly get that by using

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```